# How to do PHP echo for hyperlinks using <li> for multiple urls

Tags: php, css, html-lists

I wanted to separate URLs in a list using `<li>`, like so:

[image]

---

This is my code:

```
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Specials</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Conatct Us</a></li>  
      <li><a href="#">Create an account</a></li>
      <?php
          if ($obj_user->login) {
              echo("<li>" . "<a href='process/process_logout.php'>Logout</a>" . "</li>");}
          else {
              echo("<li>" .  "<a href='login.php'>Login</a> | <a href='signup.php'>Signup</a>" . "</li>");
          }
      ?>              
  </ul>
```

Comment: Where is the problem ? What is the question ?

Comment: i want to separate login and signup using li . right now i have added in 1 <li> for Login | Signup </li> , how to separate it

Comment: Not related to PHP..  
There is absolutely no point to separate those 2 Anchors in 2 LI.. else its CSS question ;) Inside your PHP just echo 2 time LI ..

Comment: Could you be more precise and make efforts ?

Comment: @raphael sir kindly check this image, i want to do like this! [image](http://i.imgur.com/4KFMlVk.png) but php condition  `code` <?php
          if ($obj_user->login) {
              echo("<li>" . "<a href='process/process_logout.php'>Logout</a>" . "</li>");}
          else {
              echo("<li>" .  "<a href='login.php'>Login</a> | <a href='signup.php'>Signup</a>" . "</li>");
          }
      ?> `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear at all, but here is what I understood, replace your code with :

```
  <?php
      if ($obj_user->login) {
          echo("<li>" . "<a href='process/process_logout.php'>Logout</a>" . "</li>");}
      else {
          echo("<li>" .  "<a href='login.php'>Login</a></li><li><a href='signup.php'>Signup</a>" . "</li>");
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: thanks , fixed . i will try next time more clear in question

Comment: Okay, good. Don't forget to mark the question as solved !

Comment: where is option of solved ?

Comment: On the left of answer post, there is a gray check just ender the votes which become green when you click on it.